# Element-wise sum of two lists with replacing zeros of one list by values of the third list

Tags: python, list

I have a list and want to calculate a sum of `b` and `c` element-wise. But I want list `b` if some value equals 0 to get value from `a`.

```
a=[7,5,6,9,4]
b=[0,3,4,8,0]
c=[6,8,3,0,1]
```

My solution is:

```
ab=[(b+c) if b else a for b,c in zip(b,c)]
```

which makes the following output : `[[7, 5, 6, 9, 4], 11, 7, 8, [7, 5, 6, 9, 4]]`

However, this is not what I want. I need instead of 0 in `b` it returns 7 but in my code it returns the whole list of `a`.

Comment: Try using `zip(a, b, c)`, and naming your other variables something else so they aren't also `a, b, c`.

Comment: `a` refers to the entire list, while `b` and `c` refer to individual items inside the lists `b` and `c`…

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this:

```py
a = [7, 5, 6, 9, 4]
b = [0, 3, 4, 8, 0]
c = [6, 8, 3, 0, 1]
ab = [((bi or ai) + ci) for ai, bi, ci in zip(a, b, c)]
print(ab)
# [13, 11, 7, 8, 5]
```

`(bi or ai)` will give you the value of `bi` unless that is `0` in which case it will give you `ai`. It is a bit of an "abuse" of the logical `or` operation in Python, which always returns the first operand unless that is "falsy", where it returns the second operand, but it is a commonly used idiom.

Comment: Although it's not entirely clear from OP's question whether they want `(bi or ai) + ci` or rather `(bi + ci) if bi else ai`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are always the same length you can try:

```
ab = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] == 0:
        ab.append(a[i]+c[i])
    else:
        ab.append(b[i]+c[i])
```